# CLPPLUS login failing

Tags: linux, terminal, db2, redhat, clpplus

I am trying to login to remote DB2 using clpplus but can't login as password contains `@`.

`clpplus -nw user/p@sswd@145.xx.xx.212:60000/Dbname`

but it fails saying:

```
[jcc][t4][10380][11951][4.27.25] Required property "sswd@145.xx.xx.212" is
unknown host. ERRORCODE=-4222, SQLSTATE=08001
```

Is there any work around of it?

Comment: @mao I am trying from redhat, and tried \@ but it didn't treated it as escape character rather used in passswd itself

Comment: On Linux® or AIX®, use \' around the password

Comment: Have you tried this? `clpplus -nw user/\'p@zzword\'@145.xx.xx.212:60000/Dbname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the bash shell, enclose the password with \' and additionally escape the @ with \@ (and the same for any special character inside the password, i.e. escape it with \ ).

This example works for me:

```
clpplus -nw user/\'p\@zzword\'@myhostname:50002/sample
```

Comment: that's great, i didn't know the additionally escaping the string would work